# How to auto update %spark.sql result in zeppelin for structured streaming query

Tags: apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, visualization, apache-zeppelin

I'm running structured streaming in (spark 2.1.0 with zeppelin 0.7) for data coming from kafka and I'm trying to visualize the streaming result with spark.sql

as below :

```
%spark2
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark structured streaming Kafka example")
  .master("yarn")
  .getOrCreate()
val inputstream = spark.readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "n11.hdp.com:6667,n12.hdp.com:6667,n13.hdp.com:6667 ,n10.hdp.com:6667, n9.hdp.com:6667")
    .option("subscribe", "st")
    .load()


val stream = inputstream.selectExpr("CAST( value AS STRING)").as[(String)].select(
             expr("(split(value, ','))[0]").cast("string").as("pre_post_paid"),
             expr("(split(value, ','))[1]").cast("double").as("DataUpload"),
             expr("(split(value, ','))[2]").cast("double").as("DataDowndownload"))
           .filter("DataUpload is not null and DataDowndownload is not null")
          .groupBy("pre_post_paid").agg(sum("DataUpload") + sum("DataDowndownload") as "size")
val query = stream.writeStream
.format("memory")
.outputMode("complete")
.queryName("test")
.start()
```

after it running I query on "test" as below:

```
%sql
select *
from test
```

it updates only when I running it manually, my question is How to make it updates as new data is processed (streaming visualization) as this example:

[Insights Without Tradeoffs: Using Structured Streaming in Apache Spark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJmFTXvUZgY#t=10m25s)

Comment: I'm looking at something similar.  Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the lines

```
"%sql    
select *
from test"
```

with

```
%spark
spark.table("test").show()
```